# How to cover catchError in test code coverage

Tags: angular

How can I cover the catchError in my angular test?

```
this.service.method().pipe(
  tap(ret=>{
   console.log('my return', ret);
  }),
 catchError(error=>{
   console.log('error occured');
   return throwError(error);
  })
).subscribe();
```

In my test, I mocked the service and the method.

```
let serviceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service',{
 method: of({message: 'success'})
})
```

Codes inside tap is covered but not in catchError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock an error like below:

```
let isError = false;
let serviceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service',{
 method: isError ? throwError('') : of({message: 'success'})
})
```

This way you can set `isError` in your test cases to either success or error.